# Error: ORA-06550 in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Here i have created a package,with package specification and package body,which contains a procedure which insert a row in table,package creation is successful but execution of that package is giving me error

> ORA-06550

Package specification:

```
create or replace package pkgEmp --package specification created..
as
procedure insertEmp(eno number,name varchar2,job varchar2,mgr varchar2,salary number);
end pkgEmp;
```

package body:

```
create or replace package body pkgEmp
as
procedure insertEmp(eno number,name varchar2,job varchar2,mgr varchar2,salary number)
is
begin
insert into emp values(eno,name,job,mgr,salary);
end insertEmp;
end pkgEmp;
```

Exeuting procedure insertEmp:

```
begin
pkgEmp.insertEmp(&eno,&name,&job,&mgr,&salary); --i m trying to get data in run time.
End;
```

and output:

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 18:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "&" when expecting one of the following:

   ( ) - + case mod new not null others 

   table avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev sum
   variance execute multiset the both leading trailing forall
   merge year month DAY_ hour minute second timezone_hour
   timezone_minute timezone_region timezone_abbr time timestamp
   interval date


1. begin
2. pkgEmp.insertEmp(&eno,&name,&job,&mgr,&salary);
3. End;
```

**Why I am not able to get data from User,I m using SQL*Plus**

Comment: Your error is `PLS-00103`, `ORA-06550` is only an additional information about your error (exact location in your statement).

Comment: How are you running your `insertEmp` procedure?  From SQL*Plus?  SQLDeveloper? PL/SQL Developer?  TOAD?  Something else?

Comment: @LukeWoodward its SQL*Plus,and ORacle 10g Express edition

Comment: Do you have `define` off?  Type `show define` to find out, and if it says `define OFF`, type `set define on`.  Then try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to put parameters in 'single quotes' like '&name' where the datatype is non-integer.

Thanks,
Aditya